# Has anyone conected knack to pdfgeneratorapi.com, I am trying to generate a PDF from the api data through a server link but keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, php, api, pdf-generation, doc

> This is my code I pull the knack api here

// grab record to populate template
$response = Requests::get('https://api.knack.com/v1/objects/'.$knack_object_id.'/records/'.$knack_record_id, $headers);
$data = json_decode($response->body);

> ```
> And try and conect it here
> ```

```
$key = 'xxx';
  $secret = 'xxx';
  $workspace = ' xxx';
  $resource = 'templates/xxx/output';
  $documentData =  $data;

  $data1 = [
    'key' => $key,
    'resource' => $resource,
    'workspace' => $workspace
  ];
  ksort($data1);

  $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', implode('', $data1), $secret);

  $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
      'base_uri' => 'https://us1.pdfgeneratorapi.com/api/v3/'
  ]);

  /**
   * Authentication params sent in headers
   */
  $response = $client->request('POST', $resource, [
    'body' => $documentData,
    'query' => [
      'format' => 'pdf',
      'output' => 'base64'
    ],
    'headers' => [
      'X-Auth-Key' => $key,
      'X-Auth-Workspace' => $workspace,
      'X-Auth-Signature' => $signature,
      'Accept' => 'application/json',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    ]
  ]);

  /**
   * Authentication params sent in query string
   */
  $response = $client->request('POST', $resource, [
    'body' => $documentData,
    'query' => [
      'key' => $key,
      'workspace' => $workspace,
      'signature' => $signature,
      'format' => 'pdf',
      'output' => 'base64'
    ]
  ]);

  $contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

> ```
> I thought this would generate my doc
> ```

```
{
  "response": "JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9MKNyAwIG9iago8PCAvVHlwZSA...",
  "meta": {
    "name": "a2bd25b8921f3dc7a440fd7f427f90a4.pdf",
    "display_name": "a2bd25b8921f3dc7a440fd7f427f90a4",
    "encoding": "base64",
    "content-type": "application\/pdf"
  }
}
```

> I want to conect the two apis and return a document. This returns a 500 error. I got most of the code from the website, but I belive I am conecting it wrong